# Setting maxlength in contenteditable element

Tags: jquery, html

I tried using keydown event to limit the string length of user input text in div with contenteditable attribute set to true, and it works.

```
if ($(this).html().length < maxlength)
   return true;
```

But there is one scenario where it fails.. that is when content already reach max length and user using mouse to block highlight all or some portion of the content, and afterward start typing with expectation the highlighted text will be replaced by whatever was typed.

I want to improve the detection so the js code will not block that keypress

I checked that this scenario is fine with input tag with maxlength attribute.
Here my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Va1iant/0jy8sqjd/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work by considering the length of text user has highlighted. I just know that this is possible. So the fix is to do this instead

```
if ($(this).html().length - window.getSelection().toString().length < maxlength)
    return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite interesting and the answer makes sense but it's unreadable. I refactor your code as a functional program and it works as well.

```js
$('#mydiv').on('keydown', function (e) {
  return isCtkKey(e.keyCode) || 
         (isAlphaNumKey(e.keyCode) && isSelected()) || 
         (isAlphaNumKey(e.keyCode) && isLessThanLen($(this), 4));
   
  function isSelected() {
    return window.getSelection().toString().length > 0;
  }

  function isCtkKey(keyCode) {
    return e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46
           || e.keyCode == 37 || e.keyCode == 39;
  }

  function isAlphaNumKey(keyCode) {
    return (e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57) ||
           (e.keyCode >= 65 && e.keyCode <= 90);
  }

  function isLessThanLen(ele, len) {
    return ele.html().length < len;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv" contenteditable="true">test</div>
<input type="text" maxlength="4" value="test">
```